# Last row in WPF datagrid binded to a different collection

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have an ObservableCollection A binded to a DataGrid in WPF. The user can add, remove and edit rows and this work fine.

I would like to add an 'additional row' in the end of a DataGrid, serving as a 'summary' for a given column. This row would be binded to a completly other collection B.
We can assume that number of columns in DataGrid is equal to number of elements in B.

It doesn't have to be one control - I would like to make it LOOK LIKE one. Especially, when user resizes columns, the "last row" resizes accordingly. Secondly, this row is always in the very end.

Any ideas how to achieve such a thing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use a [MultiBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260439/wpf-bind-an-element-to-two-sources).