# WPF: How to Binding single TextBox to Multiple datasource

Tags: wpf

How to Binding single TextBox to Multiple datasource?

Comment: Plese give a bit more explanation of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Multi value Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) -> [Bind an element to two sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260439/wpf-bind-an-element-to-two-sources)