# How to change the Path of existed Binding？

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I got a TextBox here

```
<TextBox ...>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="MinStepDiff" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:ImpellerArgsRule IsCanBeZero ="false"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

It's Content is rely on other ComboBox

```
<ComboBox ...>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Sample1"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Sample2"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Sample3"/>
</ComboBox>
```

If `Sample1` or `Sample3` is chosen, the TextBox should be bind to `MinStepDiff`

If `Sample2` is chosen, the TextBox should be bind to `MinTolerance` then

Both of them are properties of an object.

How can I do it?

Comment: I suppose you can try to use multibinding and a custom converter to select the appropriate value. You can find some information about multibinding here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260439/wpf-bind-an-element-to-two-sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `DataTrigger`. For this you have to create a style and give your `ComboBox` a name (here 'cb'). Because it's easier I bound to `SelectedIndex` instead of `SelectedItem`.

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>                
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Text">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Binding Path="MinStepDiff" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <local:ImpellerArgsRule IsCanBeZero="false" />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=cb}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Text">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Binding Path="MinTolerance" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```