# bind 2 column of table with 1cell in listbox

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

name first column : dateReceiving
name second column : dateSending

data :

dateReceiving     --------    dateSending

```
 2001/01/01     --------    2001/01/03
 2001/03/08     --------    2001/03/12
 2001/11/19     --------    2001/11/24
 2001/11/11     --------    2001/12/18
```

I want to display the time difference between sending and receiving in list box.

How do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using DateTime in your cells you can do something like that:

DateTime time1: your first column

DateTime time2 : your third column

TimeSpan diff = time2.Substract(time1);

Datetime:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

TimeSpan:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/system.timespan.aspx

Edit:
If your question was about multi binding =>
[Bind an element to two sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260439/wpf-bind-an-element-to-two-sources)

Answer (score 0):

Convert each date value to DateTime object and then subtract them , this will create a timespan obejct which is suitable to your situation

```
DateTime receivedDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
DateTime sendDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);

TimeSpan ts = receivedDate - sendDate;
```