# Is there a good way to bind xaml to a property that depends on multiple other properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

In one of my WPF projects, I was creating an animation storyboard in XAML which had timing properties that could be dynamically changed before kicking off the animation.  Since I needed a way to change the values in code, I bound them to properties of the class.

The basic idea was that there are two phases to the animation, and in the storyboard I use ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames which takes the total animation time, so I have properties like so:

```
public TimeSpan RaiseTime { get; set }

public TimeSpan FallTime  { get; set; }

public TimeSpan TotalTime
{ 
    get { return RaiseTime + FallTime; }
}
```

When the animation is first created, it gets the values from these properties correctly, but since they can be changed dynamically I need a way to notify the XAML that the values have changed.

It's easy enough to turn RaiseTime and FallTime into DependencyPropertys so that their changes will be reflected in the XAML bindings, but what about TotalTime?  It doesn't have a value itself so I can't turn it into a DP.

Yesturday I spent some hours searching/trying random stuff to try and get this to work and eventually got something to work using a MultiBinding to both RaiseTime and FallTime and a IMultiValueConverter, thanks to a few SO questions and a blog post:
[Bind an element to two sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260439/wpf-bind-an-element-to-two-sources)
http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2010/04/15/simplify-your-binding-converter-with-a-custom-markup-extension/

My question is:  Is this really the best way to do it?  It seems (to me atleast) such a simple task, yet it requires so much (mostly boilerplate) code to get working.  I thought there must be a simpler, less verbose way of binding TotalTime and pushing updates to XAML, but I have yet to find one.  Is there, or am I just dreaming?

Comment: You can implement IPropertyChanged and make the bindings on TotalTime work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can definitely make it work using INotifyPropertyChanged, then simply binding to the class.

The code will look something like this: **(untested code)**

```
public class PleaseChangeTheNameOfThisClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private TimeSpan _raiseTime;
    public TimeSpan RaiseTime
    { 
        get { return _raiseTime; }
        set 
        {
            if (_raiseTime != value)
            {
                _fallTime = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("RaiseTime");
                RaisePropertyChanged("TotalTime");
            }
        }
    }

    private TimeSpan _fallTime;
    public TimeSpan FallTime  
    { 
        get { return _fallTime; }
        set 
        {
            if (_fallTime != value)
            {
                _fallTime = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FallTime");
                RaisePropertyChanged("TotalTime");
            }
        }
    }

    public TimeSpan TotalTime
    { 
        get { return RaiseTime + FallTime; }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's interesting.  I've read about INotifyPropertyChanged but have only used DPs before, so I tried that first. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I tried both methods, and both worked fine, but this one is definitely less verbose.

Answer (score 1):

It may still be quite verbose, but you can in fact do this with DependencyProperties:

Attach "OnChanged" callbacks to the `RaiseTime` and `FallTime` DPs wich update the `TotalTime` DP, and make TotalTime read-only (different DP registration syntax, and only a private setter):

```
public TimeSpan RaiseTime
{
    get { return (TimeSpan)GetValue(RaiseTimeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(RaiseTimeProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty RaiseTimeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("RaiseTime", typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(MainWindow),
                                new PropertyMetadata(TimeSpan.Zero, OnRaiseTimeChanged));

private static void OnRaiseTimeChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var owner = sender as MainWindow;
    owner.TotalTime = owner.RaiseTime + owner.FallTime;
}


public TimeSpan FallTime
{
    get { return (TimeSpan)GetValue(FallTimeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FallTimeProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty FallTimeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("FallTime", typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(MainWindow),
                                new PropertyMetadata(TimeSpan.Zero, OnFallTimeChanged));

private static void OnFallTimeChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var owner = sender as MainWindow;
    owner.TotalTime = owner.RaiseTime + owner.FallTime;
}


/// <summary>
/// Read-only DP:
/// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754044.aspx
/// http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html
/// </summary>
public TimeSpan TotalTime
{
    get { return (TimeSpan)GetValue(TotalTimeProperty); }
    private set { SetValue(TotalTimePropertyKey, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyPropertyKey TotalTimePropertyKey =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("TotalTime", typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(MainWindow),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(TimeSpan.Zero));

public static readonly DependencyProperty TotalTimeProperty = TotalTimePropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
```

The default values need to add up (here: 0 + 0 = 0). After that, `OnRaiseTimeChanged` and `OnFallTimeChanged` will keep `TotalTime` updated.

Answer (score 0):

As your link suggests, [MultiBinding](http://blog.csainty.com/2009/12/wpf-multibinding-and.html) is the standard way for this.

If you want obscure solution, you can create [custom markup extension](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/03/09/creating-a-custom-markup-extension-in-wpf-and-soon-silverlight).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit more concise again. See "CallerMemberName" which is available in the latest C#.

```
public sealed class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private TimeSpan _raiseTime;
    private TimeSpan _fallTime;

    public TimeSpan RaiseTime
    {
        get { return _raiseTime; }
        private set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref _raiseTime, value))
            {
                OnPropertyChanged("TotalTime");
            }
        }
    }

    public TimeSpan FallTime
    {
        get { return _fallTime; }
        private set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref _fallTime, value))
            {
                OnPropertyChanged("TotalTime");
            }
        }
    }

    public TimeSpan TotalTime
    {
        get { return RaiseTime + FallTime; }
    }

    #region Put these in a base class...

    private bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```