# WPF/C# Bind Content from two Textboxes to a single label

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I've been trying to bind two textboxes to a single label so the label always update depending on the content of two textboxes. However without luck. I managed to solve how to bind a single one.

by using

```
Content="{Binding Text,ElementName=PersonName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

So it looks like this

```
<UserControl x:Class="FitTracker.CreateTrackItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FitTracker"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <Grid>    
    <TextBox Name="PersonName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,77,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280" />
    <TextBox Name="PersonLevel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,105,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Level" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280"/>
    <Label Name="TrackDetails" Content="{Binding Text,ElementName=PersonName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,133,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280" FontWeight="Bold" Background="#00000000" Foreground="White" />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

However I cannot do it with two text boxes. any ideas or guides that could help me on the right path.

I've been searching around for some hours now.

Comment: Note that setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is pointless in a OneWay Binding. It has no effect.

Comment: Please also note that while the question has been asked before, none of the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/260439) show how to use a MultiBinding's StringFormat instead of a Converter.

Answer (score 4):

Use a MultiBinding:

```
<TextBox x:Name="PersonName"/>
<TextBox x:Name="PersonLevel"/>
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="Name: {0}, Level: {1}">
            <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="PersonName"/>
            <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="PersonLevel"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: I'm 1 minute too late

Comment: I did read about this. I also found some of the links that people found above, my real issue here is that I am new to WPF, I usually work with web. But how do I make my Label content take the multibind string ? Thanks for helping me

Comment: Use a TextBlock. It's what a Label usually is in other frameworks. Only use a Label if you want to show Content other than text, i.e. an icon. If you *really* want to use a Label, use a MultiBinding for `<Label.Content>`. Note however that you can't use StringFormat. You would have to implement a IMultiValueConverter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a TextBlock with multiple Run elements:

```
<TextBox x:Name="PersonName"/>
<TextBox x:Name="PersonLevel"/>
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Inlines>
        <Run Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=PersonName}"/>
        <Run Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=PersonLevel}"/>
    </TextBlock.Inlines>
<TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare a new property, for example

```
public string JoinedProps {get {return PersonName+ PersonLevel;}}
```

Do not forget to notify JoinedProps' property change on both of the PersonName
 and PersonLevel fields